# Redmine: see associated revisions for git branch?

Tags: git, branch, redmine, revisions

I have redmine configured with a git repository. All was going well until we started
working on a git branch. It seems that git checkins on a branch other than master are not
being registered as "associated revisions" in the redmine issues that we are referencing.

Any ideas here?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you given a reference on the commit message like "#123" which is associated to the issue you would like to follow?

Comment: yes, I do, and I can see associated revisions for commits to master. But not on any other branches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that redmine uses `git log --all` to list revisions, which will includes every branch. Are you sure when you made your working branch that you set it up to push to redmine's git repository?

I also just tested this by creating a new branch "test" on my local repo and pushing that to a new branch in the bare repo I have redmine looking at it, and as soon as I clicked in "Repository", the new branch was available, and git commit messages where already linked to issues.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. Which version of Redmine are you running? And how do you push the branch to the repo?

Comment: My post-receive script can be found here:  https://github.com/boxerab/git-central/blob/master/server/post-receive-redmine

Comment: Found the problem: my post-receive script was running `git push`, so new branches were not being pushed to redmine repol Changing to `git push --all` fixed the problem.